# Tube AM transmitter question

Tags: transmitter, vacuum-tube

I designed an AM tube transmitter based on a crystal oscillator. Can you please tell me if this would work, or what I could improve?

[image]

Comment: Make a tap at the output coil for the antenna and use a DC blocking capacitor, or better or a second winding with 20% of the turns and one end at GND.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your answer! I'm 15 and I'm trying to learn electronics, and your answer really helped me!

Comment: You need a DC setpoint of your output stage, the typical 1 Mohm from gate to a variable negative voltage. Start with -8 V and rise carefully because the output stage can overload easily. Red anodes -> OFF. I never used this kind of AM modulation. Your EL32 needs a cathode resistor or you cut away the upper half of the audio signal.

Comment: Tube 6J5 is a triode, not a mixer type with two control grids like 6L7.

Comment: It's not clear how things are getting modulated, and you've got too many resistor-coupled circuits in there.  I **strongly suggest** that you get yourself some old ARRL handbooks from the 1950's or 1960's (to match the era of your tubes) and that you _just copy_ the circuits therein, only making tube substitutions for like = like.  Once you get a feel for how different tubes are than transistors, then you can branch out.  Manuals should be available from eBay, Abe Books, or other usual old-book suspects.

Comment: I’m mightily impressed with this design, whether it works or not.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally swapped the 6J5 with the EL32.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!

Comment: In case this circuit works well do you have a licence to transmit on 5 MHz (60 m)? As you have an interest in RF you could investigate getting an amateur radio licence. You can Google your national amateur radio society for details.